# JS 'Unexpected identifier'

Tags: javascript, json

I'm calling an API via JS and then running a if query on the response

```
var myurl = 'https://XXXX.net/api/check?';
var myaccess = 'access_key=XXXX';
var myemail = 'email=XXX@XXX.com';

var pcapi = new XMLHttpRequest();
var myNewURL = myurl + myaccess + '&' + myemail;

pcapi.open("GET", myNewURL, false);
pcapi.send();

var emailStatus = JSON.parse(pcapi.responseText);
var emailStatus = emailStatus.format_valid;
var emailStatus= JSON.stringify(emailStatus);


 if emailStatus == 'true'{
          alert('Email is correct');
  }
 else{
            alert('Email is incorrect');
  }
```

If I alert the emailStatus it comes back with "true" when the email address is valid. However when Ii try it in an 'if' statement it has an 'Unexpected identifier' error in the console. Any ideas?

Comment: Use parentheses: `if (emailStatus == 'true') {`

Comment: Why would you convert a flag into a string and then use string comparison? Just remove `var emailStatus = emailStatus.format_valid;` and use `if (emailStatus.format_valid) {`

Comment: Separately: Ajax should be **asynchronous** (that's what the "A" stands for, after all). Strongly recommend removing that `false` from the `open` call and using the `onload` callback.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition must be wrapped in parentheses, like so:

```
if (emailStatus == 'true') {
  alert('Email is correct');
} else {
  alert('Email is incorrect');
}
```